# Mathematica: How can I place the axes label differently?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, bar-chart

I am trying to place the axes label in a barchart using the "Placed" command in a position different from the end of the axis. It works in other graphics, but not with BarChart.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: FYI : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88936/363

Comment: Yes, I was aware of this discussion. "Placed" does work for me with chart labels, however, it does not with axes labels.

Comment: Can you give a minimal (non-) working example and state which version of Mathematica you are using?

Comment: Alternatively you can [add the text yourself](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9346/drawing-outside-plot-area) making use of `Epilog`,`Text`, `ImagePadding`, and `PlotRangeClipping`

Comment: Great, `Epilog` solved my problem! In addition, `Epilog` makes it a lot easier to place my (somewhat complicated) labels and comments at the proper place in the graphs. Thank you for the tip.